# CRM 365 (Web API): How to check if a user has read access to a certain CRM-record?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

Dynamics CRM 365 v9.1 (on-premise). Web API + C#.

How to check if a user has read access to a certain CRM record? I have an array of the `Lead` entity IDs. I have to filter only those for which the current user has read access.

Answer (score 0):

There is an bound function called [retrieveprincipalaccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/reference/retrieveprincipalaccess?view=dataverse-latest)

Give user entity type and ID and Target as entity and it's ID and you should have your result.

below are two code example from webapi (js)  and XMLHttpRequest.

```
// WARNING: Xrm.WebApi doesn't support Synchronous mode
// THE CODE HAS BEEN GENERATED CONSIDERING THESE WARNINGS

var execute_RetrievePrincipalAccess_Request = {
    // Parameters
    entity: { entityType: "systemuser", id: "f7c76548-0bb2-ea11-a816-000d3a3a1be9" }, // entity
    Target: { "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account", accountid : "2fe32f22-d01d-ea11-80fa-005056936c69" }, // mscrm.crmbaseentity

    getMetadata: function () {
        return {
            boundParameter: "entity",
            parameterTypes: {
                entity: { typeName: "mscrm.systemuser", structuralProperty: 5 },
                Target: { typeName: "mscrm.crmbaseentity", structuralProperty: 5 }
            },
            operationType: 1, operationName: "RetrievePrincipalAccess"
        };
    }
};

Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(execute_RetrievePrincipalAccess_Request).then(
    function success(response) {
        if (response.ok) { return response.json(); }
    }
).then(function (responseBody) {
    var result = responseBody;
    console.log(result);
    // Return Type: mscrm.RetrievePrincipalAccessResponse
    // Output Parameters
    var accessrights = result["AccessRights"]; // mscrm.AccessRights
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

---

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.2/systemusers(f7c76548-0bb2-ea11-a816-000d3a3a1be9)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.RetrievePrincipalAccess(Target=@Target)?@Target=%7B%20%22%40odata.type%22%3A%20%22Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account%22%2C%20accountid%20%3A%20%222fe32f22-d01d-ea11-80fa-005056936c69%22%20%7D", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
            console.log(result);
            // Return Type: mscrm.RetrievePrincipalAccessResponse
            // Output Parameters
            var accessrights = result["AccessRights"]; // mscrm.AccessRights
        } else {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```